# How to copy text field entity ursina?

Tags: python, text, entity, textfield, ursina

I created a text entity that you can copy using the `TextField` version of the text entity in `ursina` .
my code was:

```
test = TextField(max_lines=100, scale=3, register_mouse_input = False, text='1234')
```

**The error** :

```
NameError: name 'selectedText' is not defined. Did you mean: 'selected_text'?
```

any idea why this is happining?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the `register_mouse_input` parameter should be `True`, now the **Actual fault is in `text_field.py`**, You can find it in the **ursina/prefabs** folder, the `get_selected` function sould return `selected_text` not `selectedText`, the function's code should be:

```
def get_selected(self):
    if not self.selection or self.selection[0] == self.selection[1]:
        return None

    sel = self._ordered_selection()
    start_y = int(sel[0][1])
    end_y = int(sel[1][1])
    lines = self.text.split('\n')

    selected_text = ''
    # selected_text = lines[start_y][]

    for y in range(start_y, end_y+1):
        if y > start_y:
            selected_text += '\n'
        selected_text += lines[y][(int(sel[0][0]) if y == start_y else 0) : (int(sel[1][0]) if y == end_y else len(lines[y])) ]

    return selected_text
```

I have submitted a pull request on GitHub [here](https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/pull/503), so that they can fix it.

Comment: @Alex Krakowiak, As the pull request was merged, now you can implement it directly without making any edits, You just need to execute this command to update the ursina package : `pip install https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/archive/master.zip --upgrade --force-reinstall`